# Как открыть панель уведомлений НЕ из панели задач?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Персонализирую свой Windows 10. И хочу убрать кнопку уведомлений из панели задач. И вопрос: есть ли способ открыть панель уведомлений, если я уберу эту кнопку из панели задач?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если панель уведомлений скрыта, но не отключена, она вызывается сочетанием клавиш Win+A